# matlab error or libsvm error with related to mex files

Tags: matlab, runtime-error, svm, mex, libsvm

I am using libsvm with Matlab R2011. My problem is that it has suddenly started to give me error about mex files and it won't run again.Interesting thing is the same program was running some time back but now its not working.
Error is as follows.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Segmentation violation detected at Thu Mar 21 07:01:31 2013

.......then some stack trace files name....

This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files.
Caught MathWorks::System::FatalException

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

can anybody help me on this?
Thanks.

Comment: setup mexing enviornment once again by typing `mex -setup` in command window of MATLAB.

Comment: I already did it.After that i posted question.even re installed libsvm.Nothing changed in output.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some error in your input data format. Since libsvm is open-source, you can try debugging your mex file using Visual Studio(in Windows) by attach-to-process. google "mex file debugging" for more detail

Comment: Actually as I have said above,same code was working earlier but now suddenly it started to show this error.There was no change in input data format or code.Just change of class is happening.

Comment: By changing classes it will alter the data libsvm calculates, thus it may cause a divide by zero error inside mex.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe forget to delete some path ,you can check some paths you added before.After you added some paths,you must delete.If you do not do this,it will do not know what function to use.